# move cursor 1 word forward or backward pycharm

Tags: python, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

this has been bugging me. I'm a new mac user and also a programmer who recently learn python.

in windows, there is a shortcut to move the cursor 1 word forward or backward by hitting control and arrow key.

how do you do this in pycharm or MAC? i can't seem to find the shortcut

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not specific for pycharm

```
alt + arrow_left/right --> word backward/forward
cmd + arrow_left/right --> begin/end of line
```

Comment: darn it. my alt arrow is used by isnap to snap windows to left and right side of screen. you know any other free way to accomplish window snapping? i kinda use it a lot. thanks for sharing.

Comment: you can use the application snap under applications/utility

Comment: hmm, i don't see that listed under my applications/utility folder in my mac.